# Contact Mailing Latitude & Longitude is zero despite map feature working

Tags: geolocation, address

Looking for some help. I am trying to display geolocation on mailing address in Contact object. Any address I enter, the map renders perfect, but no Longitude or Latitude, I get nothing.

I have created formula fields, Longitude, Latitude & Accuracy.
Please note: For my client, I have renamed Mailing to Operating.

The formula I have used 
Operating Latitude = MailingLatitude
Operating Longitude = MailingLongitude
Operating Accuracy  = TEXT(MailingGeocodeAccuracy)

Also note: Maps and Location Settings - is Enable

I have check object permissions and is visible to all users - just in case that had any affected.

I have also deleted the fields and started from scratch again - with the same results

If anyone can help, that be awesome 
thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to activate **Activate** the Data Integration Rule for Data.com Geo. Then, geocodes are automatically added to existing accounts, contacts, and leads. New accounts, contacts, and leads get this information when they’re saved.

Follow this Salesforce link for more details [Get Geocodes for Addresses in Your Records](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_dot_com_clean_admin_automatically_get_geocodes_for_addresses.htm&type=5)

[image]